# How do I programatically set up an NDSolve with lots of equations?

Tags: differential-equations

I'd like to set up...

```
NDSolve[x1'[t]==2,x1[0]==0,
x2'[t]==2,x2[0]==0,
x3'[t]==2,x3[0]==0,
x4'[t]==2,x4[0]==0,
x5'[t]==2,x5[0]==0,
... etc
```

Can I somehow use x[t,1] instead of x1[t]? I'd like to make all these equations programmatically instead of typing each one out by hand.

Comment: ... but those are uncoupled!

Comment: try a syntax like this: `NDSolve[Table[{x[i]'[t] == 2, x[i][0] == 0}, {i, 2}], 
 Table[x[i][t], {i, 2}], t]`

Comment: @belisarius. ... and they might all have identical solutions!

Comment: Your toy example is too much of a toy. Could you post an example closer to the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: ...although thank you for posting a simple example rather than 27 equations full of `Subscripts` that we have to parse on our own.

Comment: A worked out example can be found in the docs for the [Method of lines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you want to solve

```
(*
{3 f[1][t]+  f[2][t]+  f[3][t]+2 f[1]′[t]+3 f[2]′[t]+4 f[3]′[t]==1,
 4 f[1][t]+4 f[2][t]+  f[3][t]+2 f[1]′[t]+  f[2]′[t]+  f[3]′[t]==1,
   f[1][t]+4 f[2][t]+  f[3][t]+3 f[1]′[t]+  f[2]′[t]+  f[3]′[t]==4}
*)
```

and then you have the matrices for the coefficients:

```
funM  = {{3, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 1}, {1, 4, 1}};
deriM = {{2, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1}};
indep = {1, 1, 4};
```

Then you may do:

```
af        = Array[f, n];
taf[t_]  := Through[af[t]]
tafD[t_] := Through[Thread[af' ][t]]
sol = DSolve[Join[Thread[deriM.tafD[t] + funM.taf[t] == indep], Thread[taf[0] == 0]], 
             af, t];
Plot[taf[t] /. sol, {t, 0, .2}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:  Have all the functions stored in one.  The following computes 100 solutions to an ode satisfying 100 differential initial conditions.

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[x[t]], x[0] == Range[100]/8}, x, {t, 0, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since they're wrapped up in one function, they're a bit hard disentangle:

```
Plot[x[t] /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But not impossible:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose[{x["Grid"] /. sol // Flatten, #}] & /@ 
  Transpose[x["ValuesOnGrid"] /. sol]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you insist on actual functions, then we can extract the values of the function and its derivatives (which `NDSolve` stores in the solution), and thread them through individual `Interpolations`.

```
xsol = With[{x0 = x["Grid"] /. sol},
   With[{y0 = Transpose[x["ValuesOnGrid"] /. sol],
         p0 = Transpose[x'[t] /. sol /. t -> Flatten[x0]]},
    MapThread[
     Interpolation[Thread[{x0, #1, #2}]] &,
     {y0, p0}]
    ]];

Plot[Evaluate@Through[xsol[t]], {t, 0, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `xsol[t_?NumericQ][n_?NumericQ] := (x[t] /. sol)[[n]]; Plot[
 Evaluate@Array[xsol[t], 4], {t, 0, 7}]`

Comment: Or `Evaluated -> True`

Comment: @belisarius I thought about the extracting parts, but I think that means you're computing all the values and throwing them all away except one. For dimension 100, it would be 100 times slower.  But the `Plot` is only three times slower.  Hmm. There something I don't understand.